# Efficient way to serialize form data to .NET ASHX/C# from JQuery

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, forms, serialization

As most people, I have read a seen a lot of examples of getting data from a form (html) and being able to effeciently handle the posted data say within an ASHX (Generic Handler) page... and from there say update a database via a stored procedure..  maybe I am trying to automate things too much?? !!

1. So I have a HTML form with say 50+ form fields.. text, checkbox, combo/dropdowns etc
2. When I click "SAVE", I want to be able to post those values to say an ASHX page which in turn will...
3. Within the ASHX page, I need to either allocate those passed form values to a business object, or for now, simply add the form values as params to a stored procedure to insert to the database.

Now rather than have lines of code getting each form value, and then assigning to the stored procedure, is there a simplified way of doing this??

I am using JQuery.. I see the serialize function.. but just need to know if the end to end solution even can be done this way, or if I do indeed have to manually retrieve the values, and assign them to an object/stored proc....

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start by writing your generic handler:

```
public class TestHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandText = "NameOfYourSP";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            foreach (string name in context.Request.Form.Keys)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + name, context.Request.Form[name]);
            }
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("success");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Which you may call like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/testhandler.ashx',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/test.ashx" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="param1" value="value1" /><br/>
    <input type="text" name="param2" value="value2" /><br/>
    <input type="text" name="param3" value="value3" /><br/>
</form>

<a href="#">Submit data</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey thanks Darin, very complete example.. many many thanks.  I guess I still need to validate and all of that which is of course fundemental, but at least there is a relatively straight forward way of getting the serialized data from the front-end, into the server/database.